# Access spring message with variable value

Tags: velocity

```
#if( $r.CATEGORY2 == 101)   #springMessage('item_1')
                        #elseif( $r.CATEGORY2 == 102)   #springMessage('item_2')
                        #elseif( $r.CATEGORY2 == 103)   #springMessage('item_3')
                        #elseif( $r.CATEGORY2 == 104)   #springMessage('item_4')
                        #elseif( $r.CATEGORY2 == 105)   #springMessage('item_5')
```

You'll see which part is very inefficient.

So I want to change it neat and simple way like this :

```
#springMessage('item_${r.CATEGORY2.charAt[2]}')
```

But the above code is not working. Please make it correct. Thank you.